# Recursion Solution for nested menu options using Typescript

Tags: typescript, recursion

I have a menu application which provides a number of options available in the menu. The options objects is very simple. It has an optionId and a type describing what type of option it is. In addition the option has a long description but I omitted it to keep things simple. The tricky part of the issue is that options can have nested option info, which provides more detail of the item. Here is a full description of the menu type, i.e. menu and the options. The JSON is processed and stored by optionId as key and Option as value in a MenuResult object.

```
        type MenuInfo = {
          menuId: string,
          menuType: string,
          options: Array<Option>
       }

       type Option = {
         optionId: string,
         type: string,
         options?: Array<Option>
     }

     
      type MenuResult ={
         menuId: string,
         menuType: string,
         options: Map<string, Option>
       }
```

Here is an example of the JSON reflecting the elements of the menu.

```
       {
         "menuId": "britanny-tavern-menu",
         "menuType": "drinks",
         "options": [
        {
         "optionId": "beverages",
         "type": "hot-options-1",
         "options": [
          {
           "optionId": "herbal",
           "type": "exotic",
           "options": [
            {
            "optionId": "green-tea",
            "type": "medicinal"
            },
            {
             "options": [
             {
              "optionId": "continental-brand",
              "type": "loose-leaves"
             },
             {
              "optionId": "asian-brand",
              "type": "tea-bags"
             }
           ]
         },
        {
          "optionId": "darjeeling",
          "type": "tea-bags"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

]
}

Unfortunately my attempt to store the data did not work. I struggle with recursion. Here is my attempt:

```
function makeMenuResult(menuJson: string){
        const menu = JSON.parse(menuJson);
        const menuObj = {} as MenuResult;
        menuObj.menuId = menu.menuId;
        menuObj.menuType = menu.menuType;
        const optionsMap = new Map<string, Option>();
        for(const optionItem of menu.options){
            const option:Option = {
                optionId: optionItem.optionId,
                type: optionItem.type
            }
            optionsMap.set(option.optionId, option);
            if(optionItem.options && optionItem.options.length > 0){
                for(const addOptionItem of optionItem.options){
                     const map = additionalOptionInfo(addOptionItem);
                     optionItem.options = map;
                }
            }

        }
    }

    function additionalOptionInfo(option: Option){
        const optionsMap = new Map<string, Option>();
        for(const optionItem of option.options){
            optionsMap.set(optionItem.optionId, optionItem);
        }
        return optionsMap;
    }
```

Please help, I don't know where to add the additional recursive step.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are trying to build a flat MenuResult, from a nested menuJson data?

Comment: Seems like there is a typo for the "green-tea" item: options seem artificially separated from optionId and type?

Comment: Yes, that is right. I want to build the menuItem list. The error in the JSON is because the actual JSOn is much larger and has more fields so I artificially tried to create a much smaller version with limited fields. The idea is that options may contain other others which in turn can have other options.  The end result is to store the relationships between the options in a map by optionId and the related option object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you want to *flatten* your nested options into the `Map` of `MenuResult.options` (i.e. have all options in a *single* Map), then you can use a recursive function to flatten the array, then convert it into a Map:

```
function flattenOptions(options: Array<Option>) {
  const result: Array<Option> = [];
  
  for (const option of options) {
    // Add the current option
    result.push(option);
    // Add potentially nested options recursively
    result.push(...(flattenOptions(option.options ?? [])));
  }

  return result;
}

// Convert the top level
function makeMenuResult(menuJson: string){
  const menu = JSON.parse(menuJson) as MenuInfo;
  // Flatten and convert the options into a Map
  const optionsMap = new Map<string, Option>();
  for (const option of flattenOptions(menu.options)) {
    optionsMap.set(option.optionId, option);
  }
  const menuObj: MenuResult = {
    menuId: menu.menuId,
    menuType: menu.menuType,
    options: optionsMap,
  }
  return menuObj;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAshB2BXAkvAZgeygXigbwCgpioBbBFAEwC4oBnYAJwEt4BzAGiJPKQBVwEWgxbsuJKBjDBmGeHVoBBRowCGIADwB5abPgA+AgF8CBUJCg6ZcnPm7Ep1+Mhr0mrTvajmhb0Z4lHPToAfiUVdW1dOUMTM0FYCgAlCDpEABtgW0IJXiphdzEvPIFIAv9xEiC5BVhVMA0RDw5LaINjUwBjGqy8gCk6G1wAAwIckgAiPJcJ2gmAIxZgVXh4EABaZYA3CEZ4dbyJyuIpilKIWagJylEAazojrwnq+UuAbS8JcYkfq5eZubzCA7NRsVKPX6-CY+S4TAAWGGA6xedHWAEYIZCJM82g9aB8sVjvoSsTinACrnDdvNVOlMSTSTC5hAAB6I5idekMqEo96fbmQ4kChlkvQUiZsRgQBCbCCqLnCknQwSw8iUDmsWkKxWk3n4-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-wwQDgPasCMAg2TyqPXF0qQFSoIirEUS6sACN9YAlL0dbyUoFoXgmiR52q+RegoLR5nbWg-MQAL8OyENplcPICM+rMeDOQRaG+kpBD+hxcVobb6gjK6DKM6KkHu9tzK6dq8lezJbC8nznoxg7gqyv9HwwAMCK9NhVpe0TMgm9HqcIlECIAgBRVROjIw65DOtoXDvbB9GuwZSfJzn425pxtIIIA)

---

On the other hand, if you rather want to convert the `MenuInfo` type (which has potentially nested array of `Option`'s) into a `MenuResult` with *also* potentially nested options, but stored as `Map`'s instead of arrays, then you also need an extra type to reflect the converted `Option` that uses such `Map` type, as already done for `MenuInfo` and `MenuResult`:

```
type MenuOption = {
  optionId: string;
  type: string;
  options?: Map<string, MenuOption>;
};

// Adjust MenuResult to use that type:
type MenuResult = {
  menuId: string,
  menuType: string,
  options: Map<string, MenuOption>
};
```

Then with these adjusted types, you can perform a recursive conversion, e.g.:

```
function optionsJson2map(options: Array<Option>) {
  const optionsMap = new Map<string, MenuOption>();
  for (const option of options) {
    // Convert Option to MenuOption
    const menuOption: MenuOption = {
      optionid: option.optionId,
      type: option.option.type,
    };
    // Recursive part
    if (option.options) {
      menuOption.options = optionsJson2map(option.options);
    }
    optionsMap.set(option.optionId, menuOption);
  }
  return optionsMap;
}

// Convert the top level
function makeMenuResult(menuJson: string){
  const menu = JSON.parse(menuJson) as MenuInfo;
  const menuObj: MenuResult = {
    menuId: menu.menuId,
    menuType: menu.menuType,
    options: optionsJson2map(menu.options),
  }
  return menuObj;
}
```

Comment: I want the nesting. Thank you for the solution to flatten but the nesting is necessary.

Comment: I included both flat and nested solutions in above answer.